# Make centered DIV inside wide DIV expand with content width

Tags: css, html

I'm using 2 divs, a parent and a child. The parent has a width of 100% and its contents are text-align'ed to center.

The child div should have a width of zero (or something close to it) and expand its width automatically with its contents, while still being centered in the parent div. Example:

```
+------------ PARENT DIV ------------+
|                                    |
|          ..some content..          |
|                                    |
|           +--CHILD DIV--+          |
|           |Inside child |          |
|           +-------------+          |
|                                    |
+------------------------------------+

+------------ PARENT DIV ------------+
|                                    |
|          ..some content..          |
|                                    |
|      +------ CHILD DIV ------+     |
|      |Inside child with more |     |
|      +-----------------------+     |
|                                    |
+------------------------------------+
```

If I put a fixed width to the child div, I can center it correctly:

```
.parent {
    width: 100%;
}
.child {
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

But that is not what I need, I need the child div to expand its width according to its content. So I tried using `float` and `nowrap`:

```
.parent {
    width: 100%;
}
.child {
    float: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

That works for the child itself, but then it is no longer centered as a content of the parent.

I can solve it by using Javascript, but I really prefere not to.

I've been looking around for similar questions in SO but I haven't find one that answers this situation exactly.

Can someone please throw me a light?

Thanks in advance for any comments.

Francisco

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `display: inline-block;` (not supported in < IE7) but you must enclose all other content in another block level element (like a `<p>` or another `<div>`)

```
.parent {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid #000;
}
.child {
    display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4kpsK/

(Click the red bordered div to add more content and see the solution in effect.)

Comment: Thank you very much! :-) I don't think I should worry too much about people using IE6 or lower. I'm sure they see at least 50% of the current web distorted already. Anyway, I suppose they will see the child div expanded to 100%, which is not what I want but it it doesn't break anything else. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your child `inline` :

```
.parent {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.child {
    display: inline;
}
```

See Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/4wXTd/1/

Comment: Inline elements don't support margin and width.

Comment: Sorry, the thing here is "text-align" center in the parent. I removed the margins and width

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work. The child div has other style attributes proper for a block element. This makes it behave exactly as if I was simply using a span element instead of a div. The answer of Kyle Sevenoaks seems to work better (inline-block).

Answer (score 0):

I think that instead of `width` you can use `max-width` and `display:inline`.
But this has drawbacks: `max-width` won't be interpreted correctly in IE (<9 at least, I think), but in Webkit/Moz/Opera browsers you should be safe.

Answer (score 0):

```
.child{display:block; margin: auto;}
```

Should work.

Comment: That makes the child div auto-width'ed to 100%. Also, display 'block' is the default display for a div.

Comment: Well, I've used this code several times for divs, images and texts, and it has alsways centered the element and the element's width is just as much as it is needed for its content.

Comment: Maybe you're not using strict validated html? Look at it for yourself. :-) http://jsfiddle.net/4wXTd/3/